# when customer is editing case, this returns to queue

Tags: email2case

when editing cases the case returns to mail to case queue.

The case owner looses the case to the queue when editing.

This problem only happens with email-to-case cases.

---

By assignment rules with 4 rules criteria:

- Case: Case OriginequalsEmail-to-case Germany
- Case: Case OriginequalsEmail-to-case sweden
- Case: Case OriginequalsWebb Sweden
- Case: Case OriginequalsWebb Germany

Assigned to 2 different queues: SupportQueueDe and SupportQueueSe

Comment: How do you assign the Cases ? By Assignment Rules or Workflow ?

Comment: By assignment rules. Please see description above. Thanks